# How to show "Choose Phone Number" Popup?

Tags: android

I built a ContactList application and I'm trying to understand how to handle contacts with multiple phone numbers. I've seen the native Phone App shows a PopUp window with all numbers and a checkbox with the text "Remember this option". Is it possible to show this same PopUp? How can I do this?

This is how I currently get the phone number (this code actually iterates through all the user's numbers and calls them all):

```
Cursor phoneCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.ID)}, null);
phoneCursor.moveToNext();
while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String normalizedPhoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).callNumber(normalizedPhoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code of the **Dialer** app could help a lot to achieve your goals.

#### The reference code:

See online source code [PhoneNumberInteraction.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-4.4_r0.9/src/com/android/dialer/interactions/PhoneNumberInteraction.java) or

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer
```

then open **DialtactsActivity**:

```
src/com/android/dialer/interactions/PhoneNumberInteraction.java
```

`PhoneNumberInteraction` class initiates phone calls or a text message. If there are multiple candidates, this class shows a dialog to pick one.
reating one of these interactions should be done through the static factory methods: i.e see: `startInteractionForPhoneCall` to start call action using given contact Uri. If there are multiple candidates for the phone call, dialog is automatically shown and the user is asked to choose one.

#### The disambiguation Dialog

PhoneDisambiguationDialogFragment is a DialogFragment used for displaying a dialog with a list of phone numbers of which one will be chosen to make a call or initiate an sms message.

```
public static class PhoneDisambiguationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment


 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        mPhoneList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(ARG_PHONE_LIST);
        mInteractionType = getArguments().getInt(ARG_INTERACTION_TYPE);
        mCallOrigin = getArguments().getString(ARG_CALL_ORIGIN);

        mPhonesAdapter = new PhoneItemAdapter(activity, mPhoneList, mInteractionType);
        final LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        final View setPrimaryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.set_primary_checkbox, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setAdapter(mPhonesAdapter, this)
                .setTitle(mInteractionType == ContactDisplayUtils.INTERACTION_SMS
                        ? R.string.sms_disambig_title : R.string.call_disambig_title)
                .setView(setPrimaryView)
                .create();
    }
```

where the adapter `mPhonesAdapter` is the **list adapter** for the list of contact's phone numbers and `setPrimaryView` (`R.layout.set_primary_checkbox`) is the **"Remember this option"** checkbox.

Notice that the `DisambiguationDialog` pop-up when there are **multiple candidates**:

see

```
   @Override
   public void (Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
```

the snippet:

```
    if (phoneList.size() == 0) {
        onDismiss();
    } else if (phoneList.size() == 1) {
        PhoneItem item = phoneList.get(0);
        onDismiss();
        performAction(item.phoneNumber);
    } else {
        // There are multiple candidates. Let the user choose one.
        showDisambiguationDialog(phoneList);
    }
```

and:

```
    void showDisambiguationDialog(ArrayList<PhoneItem> phoneList) {
    PhoneDisambiguationDialogFragment.show(((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager(),
            phoneList, mInteractionType, mCallOrigin);
```